# Add a role and give admin priviledges

Tags: users, capabilities, user-roles

I am creating a Super Admin role in wordpress Roles.

```
$capabilities=array();
add_role('Administrator', 'Administrator', $capabilities ); 
add_role('Super Admin', 'Super Admin', $capabilities) );
```

So while adding a new user I got the Role Option Super Admin.
So I added a Super User .

Now When I login to wp-admin It gives me error saying:

> you do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

What more I have to do to make it work. I dont want to use any pluggin.

I tried this too

```
add_role('Super Admin', 'Super Admin', 
array("manage_network","manage_sites","manage_network_users",
"manage_network_plugins","manage_network_themes","manage_network_options",
"read") );
```

and

```
  add_role('Super Admin', 'Super Admin', array("manage_network"=>true,"manage_sites"=>true,
"manage_network_users"=>true,"manage_network_plugins"=>true,
"manage_network_themes"=>true,"manage_network_options"=>true,"read"=>true) );
```

I want this user to access all stuff in wp-admin panel

Comment: WordPress already has a "Super Admin" role - https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#super-admin, but it is only relevant to Network installs. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

the best solution to change WORDPRESS role and capabilities is to use [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin. It is simple, very efficient and also give you power to add and modify both roles and capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

But you can do all with code without any plugins.

For example, here are my [class UserRoles](https://gist.github.com/artfulcat/a5d7b5c37553a07c3ee196b435c75564) which do that all and a bit more (maybe it's not perfect, but it works well). Just set const arrays with users & them caps (search them [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)). You can see roles 'dramatist' & 'free' as examples of new roles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a role with the exact same capabilities as an admin you can do the following:

```
$admin_capabilities = get_role('administrator')->capabilities;

add_role('custom_administrator', 'Custom Admin', $admin_capabilities);
```

Or inline:

```
add_role('custom_administrator', 'Custom Admin', get_role('administrator')->capabilities);
```

Some Notes:

- If you don't modify these copied capabilities from this custom user I would recommend you to just use the standard built-in role.
- Ideally you would put this in a hook to be executed once; like in your plugin activate hook or something similar. (Even though the `add_role()` function only adds the role if does not already exists, no matter if the passed capabilities are different).
- "I want this user to access all stuff in wp-admin panel". If you meant that you want the new role to be able to do anything to do with the administrator screen then I would copy the capabilities of the super admin role instead.